# Java array creation

Tags: java, arrays

This is just a simple question, and I can't find the answer in the documentation !

```
String args[] = new String[0];
args[0] = "test";
```

Is that correct ? Does this creates an array with 1 element or 0 elements ?

Thank you, I know, stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer in the Java doc.

Comment: The documentation you were looking for is probably [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Yes ! I ended up in the site java.sun.com when I looked

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: a easy solution to avoid index out of bounds, new Strings[]{"test",.....}. Though arrayList is much better than Arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This creates an array with length 0. The second line will give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExpection`.

Answer (score 8):

`String[] arr = new String[]{"test"}`

Answer (score 3):

> Your code is wrong. The first number states the length of the array, so it should be 1
>
> ```
> String args[] = new String[1];
> ```

The first element in an array is labeled as myArray[0]

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do the PHP-like equivalent of args[] = "new entry" then take a look at

```
List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add("test");
args.add("and some more");
args.add("and even more");
```

This works fine, and will expand your List automatically. When you need to convert it to an array, you can use:

```
String[] argArray = args.toArray(new String[args.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep it does seem a little odd - when you create the array you are declaring how many elements the array will have so 0 means no elements.  Yet when you traverse an array the first element is the 0th element not the 1st element...  Just remember that size/length are not the same as index.

Answer (score 0):

An array of length 5 is created with:

```
String myArray[] = new String[5];
```

The items in this array are indexed using 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 - note that they start at index 0, not index 1, and so go up to (array length - 1).

So

```
new String[0]
```

creates an array of length 0. Assigning to index 0 will cause an error - there are no positions in the array to assign to.

```
new String[1]
```

would create an array of length 1, with a single position at index 0, so you could then legally do:

```
myArray[0] = "happy days";
```

Comment: It makes technical sense for languages to have zero-based array indexes.  However, this has induced an uncountable number of errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
String args[] = new String[0];
```

This creates an array with no elements.  Accessing any element, even `args[0]`, would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  The number of components of the array is available in `args.length`.

```
String args[] = new String[1];
```

This creates an array with 1 element.  The element is accessed as `args[0]`. The first element is always at index 0.  Accessing any other element would cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
String args[] = new String[10];
```

This creates an array with 10 elements.  First element is `args[0]` and the last element is `args[9]`.  The last position is always one less than the size of the array.

References:

- Java tutorial on arrays: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html
- Spec: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html

  > An array object contains a number of variables. The number of variables **may be zero, in which case the array is said to be empty**. The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use nonnegative integer index values. These variables are called the components of the array. **If an array has n components, we say n is the length of the array; the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive.**

Answer (score 0):

`new String[x]` will create an empty array of Strings with size x. 
With x=0, your Array will have *no* entries, so any attempt to access its elements will result in an exception.
If you want it to have *one* element, you should specify you want *one* element: `new String[1]` will create an Array of Strings with 1  entry.

While the above parameter specifies the **size** of the array, the one you use later is the **index**. 
In many languages, [] are used for both index (in regular use) and size (when creating arrays), which may be confusing.

Simple rule: a valid index will always be >= 0, and < size of the array.

`0 <= index < size`

An index, also called offset, is how far from the start you go - how many elements into the array you step.

Answer (score 0):

`String args[] = new String[0];`

Creates an array of size `0` also called as an *empty* array. Since the array contains no elements, no index can be used on it including `0`. Usage of *any* index on it leads to `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score -2):

here's a simple & official [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: 1) Avoid links-only answers. If the link goes down, the answer is worthless. 2) The question has been answered (and there's a lot of answers already)